# Doing a 5.1 and a stereo soundtrack with same source material in Adobe Audition

Tags: mixing

I'm a CC member so up to date on the software.

I have some video clips with audio, and I am doing the sound mastering in Audition. I have the following clips to work with:

- A: Stereo input from XLR microphone.
- B: Stereo input from camera microphone.
- C: Some music clips that match music that will also be audible on the first track.

So far, I've focused on a simple stereo mix. The "A" input is the "main" audio, so it is king. I've set up a side chain compressor on the "B" track so that any voice (A is mainly speech, some music) makes it go silent, then you get audience reactions etc. whenever the main speaker is silent.

This works relatively well and I am slowly arriving at a mix that doesn't make my ears bleed.

Then I thought... how about I also make a 5.1 version, where I send the A audio to the front speakers (and center?), the B audio to the surround speakers, and the occasional music clips to the front? I think it could sound good, perhaps still with a wee bit ducking between A and B.

But does anyone know if there is an easy workflow to do mastering for both of these at the same time, in the same file? The target for this will be BluRay disc (Encore until I stumble across anything better), and I would love not to have to repeat work in two different projects / multitracks in order to have one 2.0 and one 5.1 file.

I am aware of concepts such as buses etc., but I know way too little about them to even guess if I can build something with them or not.

Anyone? Thanks for any insight!

Comment: The best thing I can think of would be to do a mixdown where right channels go to the right stereo and left channels go to left stereo with the center split evenly between.  This is effectively just saving all the channels from a 5.1 as 2 channel, but beyond that I can't think of anyway to do it without a separate mix.

Comment: I suppose you might be able to assign them to a stereo bus with balancing on each routing and then just output the bus rather than using it in the main, but I'm not sure how that would be accomplished, if it is even possible in Audition.